# Why will orElseThrow() not compile?

Tags: java, java-11

I've got a project which is set up with Java 11. I have this piece of code :

```
Lineup lineup = (Lineup) c.list()
  .stream()
  .findFirst()
  .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("not found"));
```

My IDE (Netbeans 19) refuses to compile this code. The error it gives is :

> unreported exception Throwable : must be caught or declared to be thrown

[image]

I've been staring at this piece of code for some time now, trying different approaches, but no matter what I do it fails to compile. My understanding is that this should work, but I must clearly be doing something wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This should compile. Seems like this might be an issue with NetBeans, as the error message doesn't make much sense in this context. RuntimeExceptions neither have to be caught nor have to be declared to be thrown. Do you have a custom class called `RuntimeException` or is it the one from `java.lang`?

Comment: Is it a maven project? Have you tried compiling it from the command line?

Comment: do you use a linter which demands you declare this exception? The java compiler does not force you to declare a RuntimeException

Comment: What JDK version are you using precisely? It reminds me of [Spurious error about generic exception not caught](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8056983). Similar issue in IDEA: [Bad code is green "unreported exception must be caught or declared to be thrown"](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147702/Bad-code-is-green-unreported-exception-must-be-caught-or-declared-to-be-thrown)

Comment: @Lesiak Make that an answer, what a fantastic find.

Comment: @Lesiak using Coretto JDK 11. I've resorted back to Optional<Lineup> and a manual check on isEmpty() and then throw an exception if that evaluates to true.

Comment: What is the type of `c` resp. `c.list()`? I highly suspect that [there is a *raw type* involved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2711488). That would explain why you need a type cast which you shouldn’t need with correct generic types and also would explain why the compiler doesn’t infer `RuntimeException` for the thrown type.